# What is known about the Homorphus Charm and does it cure lycanthropy?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, magical-theory, werewolf

Question inspired by reading this -> [Why was an entire minor scene omitted from the French translation of "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191210/why-was-an-entire-minor-scene-omitted-from-the-french-translation-of-harry-pott)

Please read Prof. Lockhart's quote in that question

In the quotes he claims that he performed the Homorphus charm and changed a werewolf back to human

It seems he was reading from one of his books and since his books are very popular, I can assume Homorphus charm is a real thing in Harry Potter

However, looking at Lupin in book 3, there doesn't seem to be any cure for lycanthropy at all

Is the Homorphus charm known to cure werewolf bites, in universe? Is the charm itself something Lockhart made up? What, if anything, is known about the Homorphus charm?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14586/5930

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Homorphus_Charm